# How to create user cgroups with systemd

Tags: systemd, virtualization, lxc, cgroups, container

I use unprivileged `lxc` containers in `Arch Linux`. Here are the basic system infos:

```
[chb@conventiont ~]$ uname -a
Linux conventiont 3.17.4-Chb #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Nov 28 12:39:54 UTC 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

It's a custom/compiled kernel with `user namespace enabled`:

```
[chb@conventiont ~]$ lxc-checkconfig 
--- Namespaces ---
Namespaces: enabled
Utsname namespace: enabled
Ipc namespace: enabled
Pid namespace: enabled
User namespace: enabled
Network namespace: enabled
Multiple /dev/pts instances: enabled

--- Control groups ---
Cgroup: enabled
Cgroup clone_children flag: enabled
Cgroup device: enabled
Cgroup sched: enabled
Cgroup cpu account: enabled
Cgroup memory controller: enabled
Cgroup cpuset: enabled

--- Misc ---
Veth pair device: enabled
Macvlan: enabled
Vlan: enabled
File capabilities: enabled

Note : Before booting a new kernel, you can check its configuration
usage : CONFIG=/path/to/config /usr/bin/lxc-checkconfig

[chb@conventiont ~]$ systemctl --version
systemd 217
+PAM -AUDIT -SELINUX -IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK -SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID -ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN
```

Unfortunately, `systemd` does not play well with `lxc` currently. Especially setting up `cgroups` for a non-root user seems to be working not well or I am just too unfamiliar how to do this. `lxc` will only start a container in unprivileged mode when it can create the necessary cgroups in `/sys/fs/cgroup/XXX/*`. This however is not possible for `lxc` because `systemd` mounts the `root` cgroup hierarchy in `/sys/fs/cgroup/*`. A workaround seems to be to do the following:

```
for d in /sys/fs/cgroup/*; do
        f=$(basename $d)
        echo "looking at $f"
        if [ "$f" = "cpuset" ]; then
                echo 1 | sudo tee -a $d/cgroup.clone_children;
        elif [ "$f" = "memory" ]; then
                echo 1 | sudo tee -a $d/memory.use_hierarchy;
        fi
        sudo mkdir -p $d/$USER
        sudo chown -R $USER $d/$USER
        echo $$ > $d/$USER/tasks
done
```

This code creates the corresponding `cgroup` directories in the `cgroup` hierarchy for an unprivileged user. However, something which I don't understand happens. Before executing the aforementioned I will see this:

```
[chb@conventiont ~]$ cat /proc/self/cgroup 
8:blkio:/
7:net_cls:/
6:freezer:/
5:devices:/
4:memory:/
3:cpu,cpuacct:/
2:cpuset:/
1:name=systemd:/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-c1.scope
```

After executing the aforementioned code I see in the shell I ran it in:

```
[chb@conventiont ~]$ cat /proc/self/cgroup 
8:blkio:/chb
7:net_cls:/chb
6:freezer:/chb
5:devices:/chb
4:memory:/chb
3:cpu,cpuacct:/chb
2:cpuset:/chb
1:name=systemd:/chb
```

But in any other shell I still see:

```
[chb@conventiont ~]$ cat /proc/self/cgroup 
8:blkio:/
7:net_cls:/
6:freezer:/
5:devices:/
4:memory:/
3:cpu,cpuacct:/
2:cpuset:/
1:name=systemd:/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-c1.scope
```

Hence, I can start my unprivileged `lxc` container in the shell I executed the code mentioned above but not in any other.

1. Can someone explain this behaviour?
2. Has someone found a better way to set up the required `cgroups` with a current version of `systemd` (`>= 217`)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A better and safer solution is to install `cgmanager` and run it with `systemctl start cgmanager` (on a `systemd`-based distro). You can than have your `root` user, or if you have `sudo` rights on the host create `cgroups` for your unprivileged user in all controllers with:

```
sudo cgm create all $USER
sudo cgm chown all $USER $(id -u $USER) $(id -g $USER)
```

Once they have been created for your unprivileged user she/he can move processes he has access to into his `cgroup` for every controller by using:

```
cgm movepid all $USER $PPID
```

Safer, faster, more reliable than the shell script I posted.

### Manual solution:

To answer 1.

```
for d in /sys/fs/cgroup/*; do
        f=$(basename $d)
        echo "looking at $f"
        if [ "$f" = "cpuset" ]; then
                echo 1 | sudo tee -a $d/cgroup.clone_children;
        elif [ "$f" = "memory" ]; then
                echo 1 | sudo tee -a $d/memory.use_hierarchy;
        fi
        sudo mkdir -p $d/$USER
        sudo chown -R $USER $d/$USER
        echo $$ > $d/$USER/tasks
done
```

I was ignorant about what was going on exactly when I wrote that script but reading [the cgroups documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/cgroup-v1/cgroups.html) and experimenting a bit helped me to understand what is going on. What I am basically doing in this script is to create a new `cgroup` session for the current `user` which is what I already stated above. When I run these commands in the current `shell` or run them in a script and make it so that it gets evaluated in the current `shell` and not in a `subshell` (via `. script` The `.` is important for this to work!) is that I not just open a new session for `user` but add the current shell as a process that runs in this new cgroup. I can achieve the same effect by running the script in a subshell and then descend into the `cgroup` hierarchy in the `chb` `subcgroup` and use `echo $$ > tasks` to add the current shell to every member of the `chb cgroup hierarchy`.

Hence, when I run `lxc` in that current shell my container will also become a member of all the `chb` `subcgroup`s that the current `shell` is a member of. That is to say my `container` inherits the `cgroup` status of my `shell`. This also explains why it doesn't work in any other shell that is not part of the current `chb` `subcgroup`s.

I still pass at `2.`. We'll probably need to wait either for a `systemd` update or further `Kernel` developments to make `systemd` adopt a consistent behaviour but I prefer the manual setup anyway as it forces you to understand what you're doing.

Comment: can you not just mount the cgroups dir somewhere else *(honest question)*? there was a good deal of controversy over linux cgroups and systemd last year when the cgroups maintainer apparently decided to give systemd by *name* and other *similar unnamed* apps authority over cgroups handling in userspace. not sure how it all turned out, but i know that it was pretty up in the air whether a user could do this at all a year ago.

Comment: I probably could do that but I would have to prevent systemd from mounting the cgroup root directory in the first place. Whenever I login to my machine systemd will mount the root cgroup root hierarchy under /sys/fs/cgroup and adds a user cgroup only under the systemd part of the root cgroup (You can see this above.). The difference between systemd based distros and not systemd based distros before they switch is that e.g. in Ubuntu cgroup management is not in the hands of the init daemon.

Comment: It is instead handled by a program like e.g. cgmanager. Or you can do it by hand as suggested in the link to kernel.org I posted above. I currently do not have a deep enough understanding of systemd cgroup management to fiddle with it deeper than I do now. But hopefully this will soon change.

Comment: no - i get that - ive been on arch linux for years. but i actually meant --bind mount it. never tried it myself, but i consider it might be possible. many kernel apis depend on being mounted - devpts, procfs, sysfs, and... maybe cgroups?

Comment: True, I remember you stating that in a comment to an answer I gave a long time ago. I'll inquire...

Comment: cool. best of luck. thanks for boldly going and all that, by the way.

Comment: I'm back with an answer but it doesn't involve bind mounting. I used cgmanager v0.33 rebuilding it from abs and bumping up the version as v0.33 respects the already existing system slices of systemd. I also flagged it out of date and it should be available in the repos soon. Solution in the next comment.

Comment: The trick basically is:

    `sudo systemctl start cgmanager && sudo cgm create all $USER && sudo cgm chown all $USER $(id -u) $(id -g) && sudo cgm movepid all $USER $PPID`. The last command needs to be run in the current shell in order to add it to the new cgroup for `$USER`.

Comment: The last command has to be `sudo cgm movepid all $USER $$` of course. Otherwise you will add the parent id of the current shell to your `cgroup`.

Comment: Note that `cgmanager` is not compatible with modern `systemd`. For details, see https://lwn.net/Articles/618411/

Answer (score 0):

Actually in archlinux, this won't work with e.g. a unprivileged user (recommended when using unpriv. lxc containers). i.e. that user doesn't have sudo :)

Instead, define group in /etc/cgconfig.conf, activate cgconfig, cgrules (libcgroup in AUR),
add cgrules as well, done.. unpriv. user will also have the same rights.

In systemd 218 (I don't know when , but seems one has to add two more conditions as they are not set when created from the cgconfig way):

```
cat /etc/cgconfig.conf

group lxcadmin {
perm {
    task {
        uid = lxcadmin;
        gid = lxcadmin;
    }
    admin {
        uid = lxcadmin;
        gid = lxcadmin;
    }
}
cpu { }
memory { memory.use_hierarchy = 1; }  
blkio { }
cpuacct { }
cpuset { 
    cgroup.clone_children = 1;
    cpuset.mems = 0;
    cpuset.cpus = 0-3; 
}
devices { }
freezer { }
hugetlb { }
net_cls { }
}

cat /etc/cgrules.conf
lxcadmin        *       lxcadmin/
```

Assuming namespace is compiled in kernel.

This is a template, cpus can be according to how many cores you have, mem can be set to some actual value, etc etc.

EDIT 2: Finally, in systemd, should you wish to use auto-start with such an unprivileged user, you can do:

cp /usr/lib/systemd/system/lxc{,admin}\@.service ,
then add User=lxcadmin

and enable it for lxcadmin's container called lolz systemctl enable lxcadmin@lolz.

Comment: Thank you @Anthon, I never can ever get the code formatting right in these websites ,x

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the late reply. Your first point, "Actually in archlinux, this won't work with e.g. a unprivileged user (recommended when using unpriv. lxc containers). i.e. that user doesn't have sudo :)" does not stand as you only need your `root` administrator to create and `chown` you into all `cgroup` controllers. This is perfectly fine and secure.`movepid` can be done without `root` rights and hence, the unpriv. user does not need any `sudo`rights. (Btw, `libcgroup` is not supposed to be used anymore. RHEL and others have deprecated it.)

Comment: @Brauner. How do you autostart at boot, your unprivileged user's containers then? Actually your solutions listed only worked (and implied) a sudo user. Mine did not. You asked how to fix it. Anyway, there has just been an update, and cgconfig now fails to start, as user.slices are added automatically, ahead of the cgconfig settings it seems. These are lacking any user permissions (possibly a regression bug, am looking into it now). I didn't say it was the _best_ solution. It was *the/a* solution to your inquiry. :) But my containers aren't starting on boot now, grrr.

Comment: The reason I listed systemctl enable lxcadmin@container was so root could decide to run a unpriv container on boot. If the user himself uses it in --user (land), it would only boot when he logs in, not very useful for a server. And a note on your comment. chowning a user into all controllers, allows that user to start moving pid's into host space, I believe, which is quite a security risk.

Comment: Erm, that seemingly is what you were doing with your method initially listed I guess, but look at this, even if it's ubuntu systemd package https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd/+bug/1413927 But something was updated in past days changing the logic.. I am trying to track it down.

Comment: debugging will go to our forum: bit since some might read this, I will add: in my lxc server, cgmanager.service fails due to ordering cycle at boot. cgconfig however still worked by adding the cgroups. The recent upgrade to cgmanager broke cgconfig, making user.slice add to some controllers (but not all and seemingly randomly); and also potentially with wrong permissions. I might yield an answer on forum when yet again, I have hacked this gobsh***e ,x

Comment: (Answer seems ot be hugetlb was removed as a cgroup, being used as hugetlbfs.. so remove that in cgconfig.conf and one is back up running).

Answer (score 0):

So I ran into the same problem when trying to get LXC unpriviliged containers working on CentOS 7. I didn't want to use `cgmanager` because I don't like introducing any additional services if not absolutely required. What I ended up doing instead is patching systemd using some patches from the ubuntu package and one custom patch to expand the list of cgroup controllers. I have the sources needed to build an RPM on my GitHub account at https://github.com/CtrlC-Root/rpmdist. I also have patched versions of shadow-utils (for subuids and subgids) and pam (for loginuid). After I install these RPMs and configure a user to run unpriviliged containers (assign subuids & subgids, allocate veth pairs in lxc-usernet, create .config/lxc/default.conf, etc) I can run LXC unprivileged containers just fine.

EDIT: Another reason I didn't want to use cgmanager is because I didn't want my regular users to have to use sudo at all. Regular users should be able to log in and everything should "just work" out of the box.

Comment: Did any of these fixes make it into CentOS distribution? I am having the same problems but you are the first one to tell me code changes helped fixed the problem.

Comment: No they didn't and I don't have a copy of that repository anymore. However you could probably reproduce my work. Start by downloading the sources for the kernel package in both CentOS 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Look through all the non-upstreamed patches on the Ubuntu kernel and you'll eventually find their changes to the cgroup controllers. Copy the patches over to the CentOS kernel package and modify them until they can be applied cleanly. You'll have to do this for the userland programs too. IIRC the shadow-utils and pam patches came from upstream and not the Ubuntu variants.

Comment: would this require me to build a new version of the kernel and build my own centos7 home-brew version in order to use this?

Comment: Yes and then you'd have to maintain it as the upstream version changes, for example to pull in new bug or security fixes. It takes work and ultimately that's why I abandoned this approach once there was a better one available which in my case was switching to a different linux distribution that shipped a kernel that worked out of the box.

Comment: What linux distribution did you end up going with? Was it from the Fedora lineage?

Comment: It was Arch Linux. I wanted the latest upstream software versions more than stability so it made sense for me. I don't know if any of the RHEL based distributions support this use case out of the box.